# Terminal font behaviour

Tags: fonts, unicode

Terminal font behavior is different from other fonts.

For example, here is a screenshot of terminal font glyphs. Why does it have limited glyphs and is not showing Unicode codepoints?

Is there any relation between terminal font and codepage 437, because when I move the cursor to a specific font it shows codepoint value of page 437.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you check, you can see that [Code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) actually has different characters in the non-ASCII region. This is [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850).

Answer (score 1):

It is because Terminal is based upon code page 437 and is not aligned with Unicode.

Console font rendering supports only Unicode characters in BMP (in other words: below U+10000). Only simple text rendering is supported (so European — and some East Asian — languages should work fine — as far as one uses precomposed forms). [There is a minor fine print here for East Asian and for characters U+0000, U+0001, U+30FB.]

Comment: thanks for the answer , so is that mean that all command prompt is linked with codepage 437 , what if i change the locale of system , will it effect terminal font nautre .  it will be big help if you could provide reference of 'Terminal is based upon code page 437'

Comment: It would be hard to find a true reference that tells you that Terminal is based on CP437, but you can [compare the glyphs](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/globalization/gcoc/attachments/CP00437.pdf). BTW, Terminal is a .FON font file, i.e., a .EXE (renamed) with only a .FNT resource with bitmap glyphs. In Win7 the file is **vgaoem.fon**.